# Can you check for null when a constructor call another constructor using the object given to the first constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

If I have a class with two constructors as follows:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(string name)
    {...}

    public Foo(Bar bar): base(bar.name)
    {...}
}
```

is there some way that I can check if bar is null before I get a null reference exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **static** method to do this:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(string name) {
        ...
    }

    public Foo(Bar bar): base(GetName(bar)) {
        ...
    }

    static string GetName(Bar bar) {
        if(bar == null) {
            // or whatever you want ...
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");
        }
        return bar.Name;
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is horrendous and wrong.  Throwing exceptions during construction means the object is not successfully constructed which means destructors do not get called.  If you already assigned resources that DO need to be disposed properly you have now broken the class in a subtle hard to debug way.  Exceptions during construction: just say no.  Foo instead should not barf if name is null.  Or you can extract the name setting code into a static which both constructors can call.

Comment: @Dirk meh, about 99.99% of c# classes *do not have* a finalizer

Comment: true, it is only 0.01% horrendous.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(Bar bar): base(bar == null ? default(string) : bar.name)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

alternatively let the bar-class handle with an object of the bar-class and throw an ArgumentNullException if you'd like

Comment: This method seems fine, but I chose the static version as the answer for one simple reason, readability.  Especially as I need to access 4 properties of the bar class which would make the constructor very unreadable

Comment: :) that's ok ... i would rather tend to the ctor in the bar class which handles bar-objects ... have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

```
public Foo(Bar bar): base(bar == null ? "" : bar.name)
{...}
```